# Extract data from site and different pages and save to csv

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, export-to-csv

I am working with selenium webdriver to search and extract data from this site https://www.idealista.com/venta-viviendas/marbella-malaga/

I want to get a table with the price of each of the houses (class item_price), the number of rooms (class item_detail) and the sq. meters (class item_detail).

I believe I have to use the driver.find_elements() method, but I don't know where to add it and how to make sure we add all prices, rooms and sq. meters in a table with three columns.

I got this code so far but it doesn't work. I see FireFox going though pages but it seems it doesn't keep and store the data in houses.csv. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
import csv
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.idealista.com/venta-viviendas/marbella/las-chapas-el-rosario/")

pages_remaining = True
price = []
rooms = []
size = []

while pages_remaining:

    price = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("item-price")
    rooms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'hab.')]")
    size = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'm²')]")
    houses = [price, rooms, size]
    try:
        # Checks if there are more pages with links
        next_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("icon-arrow-right-after")
        next_link.click()
        time.sleep(10)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        rows_remaining = False

with open('houses.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerows(houses)

print(houses)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) link and after at [this](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) that you will find some errors on your code.

Comment: I did, and I have changed the code a bit. Could you please review? rooms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "hab.")]").text       SyntaxError: invalid syntax.... and it points to hab.

Comment: Post full exception.

Comment: Users/Josete/Documents/workspace_python/webdriver/venv/bin/python /Users/Josete/Documents/workspace_python/webdriver/webdriver.py
  File "/Users/Josete/Documents/workspace_python/webdriver/webdriver.py", line 17
    rooms = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), "hab.")]").text
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: You have `"` inside your xpath. Try use `'` as external closes.

Comment: I did, it fixed the error. Thanks. Now I get this   
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Josete/Desktop/ListOfElements.py", line 25, in <module>
    except NoSuchElementException:
NameError: name 'NoSuchElementException' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //*[contains(text(), 'siguiente')]

I am working on it now